# How to animate a single fragment inside an Activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am making a simple booklet like app in which the MainActivity has 1 fragment that contains a Multiline Text View and a Button. On Click of the button, I am loading new content for the TextView from SQLite database.

I want to put an animation for the fragment while changing the content such as flip..
I searched a lot of tutorials but there is no solution for a single Fragment.

My Fragment looks like this...and I want to show some effects on click of 2 imageViews (buttons)

```
public class DisplayJokesFragment extends Fragment {

    Activity activity;
    TextView joke;
    ImageView imgview1, imgview2;
    private Cursor cursor;

    public static DisplayJokesFragment createFunnyJokesFragment(Cursor cursor) {
        DisplayJokesFragment fragment = new DisplayJokesFragment();
        fragment.setCursor(cursor);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_funny_jokes,
                container, false);
        joke = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        imgview1 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imgview2 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        //MOVE NEXT JOKE
        imgview2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    joke.setText(Html.fromHtml(cursor.getString(1)));
                } else {
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    joke.setText(Html.fromHtml(cursor.getString(1)));
                }
            }
        });     

        //MOVE PREVIOUS JOKE
        imgview1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (cursor.moveToPrevious()) {
                    joke.setText(Html.fromHtml(cursor.getString(1)));
                } else {
                    cursor.moveToLast();
                    joke.setText(Html.fromHtml(cursor.getString(1)));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just set animation to your TextView. When you Click in button - you start animation and set some text to your view.

If you want you can create animation in xml file.

For example you can do it like this:

```
final TextView yourTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);
final AlphaAnimation animateS = new AlphaAnimation(1,0);
final AlphaAnimation animateF = new AlphaAnimation(0,1);
animateS.setDuration(700);
animateF.setDuration(700);
animateS.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

}
@Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                yourTextView.setAnimation(animateF);
                animateF.start();
                yourTextView.setText("New Text");
            }
@Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
}
        });
yourTextView.setText(str);
        yourTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                yourTextView.setAnimation(animateS);
                animateS.start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer...Let me try!